# Central limit theorem and the weak law of large numbers

Tags: probability, probability-theory, central-limit-theorem, law-of-large-numbers

I am trying to understand the intuition of the CLT. If I have a sequence of R.V $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$

where $X_i\overset{iid}{\sim} f(x;\mu,\theta)$ where $E[X_i]=\mu$ and $Var[X_i]=\theta$

it is my understanding that by the SLLN there exists a set $N\subset\Omega$ with $P(N)=0$ such that for all $\omega \in \Omega-N$ the following is true:
$$\overline{X_n}(\omega)\rightarrow \mu$$

I understand this from a real analysis perspective that $\overline{X_n}$ converges to a constant function a.s. that is a degenerate R.V over the set $\Omega-N$. With the WLLN implying something similar where the set where convergence does not occur eventually has a small probability as n gets larges and converging to 0.

Now the central limit theorem implies

$$\sqrt{\frac{n}{\theta}}\bigg[\overline{X_n}-\mu\bigg]\rightarrow Z$$

where $Z\sim N(0,1)$ that is the standardized sample mean converges to a RV(function) whose distribution is a standard normal. If I am wrong so far please correct me?

Why does the sample mean converge to a degenerate RV in probability and almost surely but then the standardized version converge to a non-degenerate random variable? The only thing I can come up with is that unlike convergence a.s, convergence in probability does not guarantee a defined set where this always holds so we can have $\omega \in \Omega $ where will not always guarantee convergence then this provides a non-degenerate RV where the central mass is at $E[X]=\mu$

Comment: If I understood well, you are thinking that convergence in probability or almost surely means surely convergence. No, it will not be that deterministic, if you read the definitions. The sample mean converges in probability to a constant (population mean), and the associated standardized "error" has a limiting distribution (gaussian, in this case).

Comment: @Celine Harumi Then for a.s convergence, how does the set $\Omega-N$  not imply sure convergence. The RV(function) is deterministic.  The randomness occurs from the selection of $\omega$.  if all omegas converge to a constant $\mu$  except for a null set how does this not imply sure convergence to a constant function. If it is convergence in probability then I understand your limiting error distribution argument

Comment: Are you confused with $Z$ not being a degenerate random variable? Did you take into account the term $\sqrt{n}$? Perhaps, you saw that $\bar X_n\to\mu$ a.s., and THEN, $\sqrt{n}(\bar X_n-\mu)\to Z$ in distribution with $Z=0$ instead $Z\sim N(0,\theta)$. It's not correct though. The presence of $\sqrt{n}$ changes the asymptotic order of your random variable.

Comment: You are right forgot the $\sqrt{n}$ term

Comment: @CelineHarumi Is it safe to say that the CLT implies that for large n that $\overline{X}_n\approx \mu+\sqrt{\frac{\theta}{n}}Z$   where $Z\sim N(0,1)$  and $\overline{X}_n$ will eventually converge in probability to a degenerate R.V ( a constant $\mu$ and therefore to a degenerate distribution.

Comment: At the moment, I could only state the following conclusion: from CLT, $\sqrt{n}(\bar X_n -\mu)$ converges in distribution and then it is $O_p(1)$. It is equivalent to say that $\bar X_n=\mu +O_p(1/\sqrt{n})$. From this, you can obtain the desired convergence in probability. This is safe.  It should be mentioned that for finite $n$ we couldn't say that $Z$ is Gaussian. So I see your (finite sample) approximation as heuristics/empirical (although reasonable).